# Slow application. Can someone advice me what to do?

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

My app run little slowly and it becuase I use a lot in AlertDialog box.
I trying to give the user option to select and I do it with ImageButtns in AlertDialog.
[image]

its start with 6 ImageButton after he choose one of them he go to another 5 ImageButton based on what he selected, after that 4 ImageButton and go on. Like the picture.
The app go very slow, can someone advice me what to do?
Maybe use something else insted Alert Boxses.

The code of the Alerts for only one route Down here:

```
 btnPattern.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ImageButton mSkirt = dialogAlert(R.layout.activity_pattern_pop_up,R.id.btnSkirt,0);
            mSkirt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    ImageButton mSkirtStraight = dialogAlert(R.layout.activity_skirt_pop_up,R.id.btnSkirtStraight,1);
                    mSkirtStraight.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            ImageButton mSkirtStraightMini = dialogAlert(R.layout.activity_skirt_straight_pop_up,R.id.btnSkirtStraightMini,2);
                            mSkirtStraightMini.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(View v) {
                                    ImageButton mSkirtStraightMiniHigh = dialogAlert(R.layout.activity_skirt_straight_mini_pop_up,R.id.btnSkirtStraightMiniHigh,3);
                                    mSkirtStraightMiniHigh.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onClick(View v) {
                                            photoSorter.addImages(MainActivity.this, id[0]);
                                            photoSorter.addImages(MainActivity.this, id[1]);
                                            for (AlertDialog dialog:dialogPattern)
                                                dialog.dismiss();
                                        }
                                    });
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

And the function dialogAlert here:

```
public ImageButton dialogAlert(int layout,int btnImage,int index){
    AlertDialog.Builder mPattern = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
    View mPatternView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(layout,null);
    ImageButton mSkirt = (ImageButton) mPatternView.findViewById(btnImage);
    mPattern.setView(mPatternView);
    dialogPattern[index] = mPattern.create();
    dialogPattern[index].show();
    return mSkirt;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Fragments and load fragments based on Clicks , Use Listener CallBacks from fragments get input from fragment

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But i dont know if fragment will be ok for me, because i want to give the user option to select each time diffrent pattern abd if from the last fragment i return to the mainActivity with intent it will start the mainActicity with a blank and dont remember the previues cohise..

Comment: I did work on Fragments , you can take input from fragment through callback listeners and then can give that input to other fragments as well ,

Comment: Fragments will speed up your app for sure !

Comment: i want the last fragment return to mainActivity and send to the mainActivity the option user select. i search on youtube about callback but i didnt see how can i close all the fragment i open and return to the mainActivity with selected option...